# Why Go sets different content-type based on where I declared the buffer

Tags: go, video-streaming

I experiment with steaming video and can't explain the following behaviour.
I get different response headers from Go's net/http server, from two different handlers, when the only difference is where I declare my buffer.

In the code below there are two handlers where the only difference is that one handler declares the buffer locally. in that version the streaming works correctly, Chrome stream the video, I see it gets response with Transfer-Encoding: chunked and content-type: video/mp4.

In the second version where the buffer is an input param, Chrome doesn't stream the video and the headers are different.

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "io"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    file := "/Users/someUser/Documents/Zoom/Ronen/zoom_0.mp4"

    f, err := os.Open(file)
    defer f.Close()

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    http.ListenAndServe(":9008", GetVidHandler(f))
}

//This implementation works, buff is declared locally.
//I get header of content-type video/mp4
func GetVidHandler(f *os.File) http.HandlerFunc {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        offset := int64(0)
        var buff [4096]byte
        for {
            n, _ := f.ReadAt(buff[:], offset)
            offset += int64(n)
            re := bytes.NewReader(buff[:])
            io.Copy(w, re)
        }
    }
}

//This implementation doesn't stream, buff is input param
//I get header of content-type octet-stream
func GetVidHandler(f *os.File, buff [4096]byte) http.HandlerFunc {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        offset := int64(0)
        for {
            n, _ := f.ReadAt(buff[:], offset)
            offset += int64(n)
            re := bytes.NewReader(buff[:])
            io.Copy(w, re)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: After the read you must not use buff past n. You're copying garbage as soon as there's a read that's shorter than any previous read.

Comment: Also, in the second version concurrent requests are stepping on each other's toes because they use the same buffer space. I wouldn't be surprised if the request for the favicon messes things up.

Comment: To add to previous comments:  Neither handler exits. Fix by breaking from the loop on read error.   The bytes.NewReader/io.Copy code can be simplified to `w.Write(buff[:n])` (this also fixes problem mentioned in first comment).  The best fix is to use [ServeFile](https://godoc.org/net/http#ServeFile).

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for the comments, but fixing them still don't change the behaviour. 
Foe example the following code gets
write tcp 127.0.0.1:9008->127.0.0.1:60443: write: broken pipe

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "io"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

type Viewer struct {
    ch   chan []byte
    buff [3][4096]byte
}

func main() {
    file := "/Users/someUSer/Documents/Zoom/Ronen/zoom_0.mp4"

    f, err := os.Open(file)
    defer f.Close()

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    m := make(map[int]*Viewer)
    start := make(chan struct{})

    go func() {

        offset := int64(0)
        <-start
        log.Println("Starting...")
        i := 0
        for {
            var b [4096]byte
            n, err := f.ReadAt(b[:], offset)
            if err != nil {
                log.Println(err)
                return
            }

            offset += int64(n)
            for _, v := range m {
                copy(v.buff[i%3][:], b[:n])
                v.ch <- v.buff[i%3][:n]
            }
            i++
        }

    }()

    http.ListenAndServe(":9008", GetVidHandler(m, start))

}

func GetVidHandler(m map[int]*Viewer, start chan struct{}) http.HandlerFunc {

    i := 0

    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

        current := i
        v := &Viewer{ch: make(chan []byte)}
        m[current] = v
        i++
        select {
        case start <- struct{}{}:
        default:

        }
        cn, ok := w.(http.CloseNotifier)
        if !ok {
            http.NotFound(w, r)
            return
        }
        // flusher, ok := w.(http.Flusher)
        // if !ok {
        //  http.NotFound(w, r)
        //  return
        // }

        // Send the initial headers saying we're gonna stream the response.
        // w.Header().Set("Transfer-Encoding", "chunked")
        // w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "video/mp4")
        // w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
        // // flusher.Flush()

        // b := <-v.ch
        // log.Println(current, "-Writing ", len(b), " Bytes")
        // log.Printf("%d - WRITE - First 100 bytes %v\n", current, b[:100])
        // w.Write(b[:len(b)])

        // flusher.Flush()
        for {
            select {
            case <-cn.CloseNotify():
                log.Println("Client stopped listening")
                return
            default:
                b := <-v.ch
                re := bytes.NewReader(b[:])
                _, err := io.Copy(w, re)
                if err != nil {
                    log.Println(err)

                }
            }
        }

    }

}

//Works
// func GetVidHandler(f *os.File) http.HandlerFunc {

//  return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
//      offset := int64(0)
//      var buff [4096]byte
//      for {
//          n, _ := f.ReadAt(buff[:], offset)
//          log.Printf("WRITE - First 100 bytes %v\n", buff[:100])

//          offset += int64(n)
//          re := bytes.NewReader(buff[:])
//          io.Copy(w, re)
//      }
//  }

// }
```